# Doctrine - Access metadata saved on linking table

Tags: orm, doctrine, many-to-many, inner-join

I have 3 tables:

```
# schema.yml
Author:
  connection: store-rw-library
  tableName: lib_author
  actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
  columns:
    id:
    type: integer(4)
    unsigned: 1
    primary: true
    autoincrement: true
  name:
    type: string(50)
    notnull: true

Book:
  connection: store-rw-library
  tableName: lib_book
  actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
  columns:
    id:
    type: integer(4)
    unsigned: 1
    primary: true
    autoincrement: true
  name:
    type: string(50)
    notnull: true
  relations:
    Author:
      class: Author
      foreignAlias: Books
      refClass: LinkingAuthorBook

LinkingAuthorBook:
  connection: store-rw-library
  tableName: lib_linking_author_book
  columns:
    author_id:
      type: integer(4)
      unsigned: 1
      primary: true
    book_id:
      type: integer(4)
      unsigned: 1
      primary: true
    created_at:
      type: timestamp(25)
      notnull: true
  relations:
    Author:
      foreignAlias: AuthorBooks
    Book:
      foreignAlias: AuthorBooks
```

Per the notes via [Doctrine docs](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/pl/yaml-schema-files#relationships%3aone-to-one), I established the relationships as M:M between Author and Book using the LinkingAuthorBook table.

Now, I am trying to get all the books authored by a specific author, in one query, something like:

```
class AuthorTable
{
    public function getAuthor($id)
    {
        $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->select('a.id AS author_id')
            ->addSelect('a.name AS author_name')
            ->addSelect('b.AuthorBooks')
            ->from('Author a')
            ->innerJoin('a.Books b')
            ->where('a.id = ?', $id);

        $result = $q->fetchArray();            
    }
}
```

The resulting query from the above DQL construct:

```
SELECT
  m.id AS m__id,
  m.name AS m__1,
  m2.id AS m2__id,
  m2.name AS m2__1,
  m.id AS m__0,
  m.name AS m__1
FROM 
  lib_author m
INNER JOIN
  lib_linking_author_book m3 ON (m.id = m3.author_id)
INNER JOIN
  lib_book m2 ON m2.id = m3.book_id
WHERE
  (m.id = '163')
```

From the above query, I see that it is correctly doing the joins, but how do I access the `LinkingAuthorBook.created_at` metadata column, established in my schema.yml file?

The only way I was able to get access to the metadata column was by adding an explicit `innerJoin` to `LinkingAuthorBook` (with associated book_link alias), but this resulted in another join in the resulting SQL. Which doesn't make sense because it has access to the data it needs from the original query.

**-- Update (3.7.2012) --**

The problem is still occurring, if I setup a loop to iterate over all the books belonging to an author, I cannot combine the meta data from the LinkingAuthorBook table or the Book table without forcing another query.

Updated query:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->from('Author a')
    ->innerJoin('a.Books b')
    ->innerJoin('b.LinkingAuthorBook ab ON a.id = ab.author_id AND b.id = ab.book_id')
    ->where('a.id = ?', $id);
```

Example loop from LinkingAuthorBook -> Book:

```
foreach ($author->getLinkingAuthorBook() as $link) {

    // Works fine, no extra query
    var_dump($link->getCreatedAt());

    // Forces an extra query, even though 'name' is the column name
    //  So even though doctrine uses lazy-load, it should be able to 
    //  get this data from the original query
    var_dump($link->getBook()->getName());  
}
```

And the same for the following loop of Book -> LinkingAuthorBook:

```
foreach ($author->getBook() as $book) {

    // Forces extra query
    var_dump($book->getLinkingAuthorBook()->getCreatedAt());

    // No extra query
    var_dump($book->getName());
}
```

My work around:

```
class Book
{
    public $meta;
}

class AuthorTable
{
    public function getAuthor($id) 
    {
        $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->from('Author a')
            ->innerJoin('a.Books b')
            ->innerJoin('b.LinkingAuthorBook ab ON a.id = ab.author_id AND b.id = ab.book_id')
            ->where('a.id = ?', $id);

        $author = $q->fetchOne();

        // Manually hydrate Book Meta
        foreach ($author->getLinkingAuthorBook() as $authorBook) {
            $authorBooks[$authorBook->getId()] = $authorBook;
        }

        foreach ($author->getBook() as $book) {
            $book->meta = $authorBooks[$book->getId()];
        }
    }
}
```

So now, I can iterate over books, with meta, without forcing an extra query:

```
foreach ($author->getBook() as $book) {

    // No extra query
    var_dump($book->meta->getCreatedAt());

    // No extra query
    var_dump($book->getName());
}
```

**-- Update (3.8.2012) --**

So I was able to prove that in the following code:

```
foreach ($author->getBooks() as $book)
{
    echo $book->getName().'- '.$book->LinkingAuthorBook[0]->getCreatedAt().'<br/>';
}
```

Each iteration caused a new query to be issued in order to get the `createdAt` value. I did this by issuing the following commands in MySQL:

```
mysql> set global log_output = 'FILE';
mysql> set global general_log = 'ON';
mysql> set global general_log_file = '/var/log/mysql/queries.log';
```

Then I tailed `/var/log/mysql/queries.log` and was able to see the additional queries being generated. So, as far as I can tell, manually hydrating the Book::Meta object after initial query, is the only way to access the metadata without having to issue another query.

Comment: Lol, this made google's search already. Circular reference ftw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion:

```
//one query for fetching an Author, his books and created_at for the each book
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->from('Author a')
            ->innerJoin('a.Books b')
            ->innerJoin('b.LinkingAuthorBook ab ON a.id = ab.author_id AND b.id = ab.book_id')
            ->where('a.id = ?', 1);

$author = $q->fetchOne();

echo 'Author: '.$author->getName().'<br/>';
echo 'Books: <br/>';
foreach ($author->getBooks() as $book)
{
    echo $book->getName().'- '.$book->LinkingAuthorBook[0]->getCreatedAt().'<br/>';
}
```

Only one query you realy need.

Comment: Does this issue another query? I got caught using Objects only to find out a page that I ported from arrays to ORM went from 2 queries to 21.

Comment: So I switched the fetchArray() to fetchOne() to gain access to the object to support the fluent interface you described above. I can do `var_dump($result->getId());` and it works, but when I do `var_dump($result->getName());` it adds another query: `SELECT m.id AS m__id, m.name AS m__name, m.created_at AS m__created_at, m.updated_at AS m__updated_at FROM lib_author m WHERE (m.id = '163') LIMIT 1`. This doesn't make sense, why is it issuing another query when I attempt to retrieve data threw a known accessor?

Comment: Doctrine use a Lazy Load pattern. In your query you select an author_name instead of name, see: `a.name AS author_name`
You can access it using `$result->getAuthorName()`.
When you try to access to name using `$result->getName()` doctrine generate another query to retrieve a name.

Comment: Updated post, let me know what you think.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I tinkered with the info you have provided and posted my findings in a 2nd update in OP.